# How to apply a function to a list of lists

Tags: java, kotlin, flatmap

I know of the flatMap operation but don't fully understand how it works.

I have a class:

```
class Days() {
  List<Date> dates;
}
```

Then I have a list of these objects

```
List<Days> month
```

And I want to do something to each of the dates in this object (for example convert them to a string) and then get back a single list with all of those strings.

How would one do this?

Comment: Your `class Days` definition and your `month` definition are not Kotlin definitions.  Are you trying to use a flatMap on java classes?

Answer (score 1):

If that `Days` class were in Kotlin, you wouldn't make `dates` nullable probably. The `flatMap` call can use a simple function reference then:

```
class Days(val dates: List<Date> = emptyList())

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val manyDays = listOf(Days(), Days())
    manyDays.flatMap(Days::dates).forEach(::println)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I, of course, figured it out right after posting this but I figured I should put my answer here in case others discover this.

```
month.flatMap{
  it.dates ?: listOf<Days>() 
}.map{
  //do your work on the objects here
}
```

Comment: Use `it.dates.orEmpty()` or at least `it.dates ?: emptyList()`